# How to Display Two ArrayList values in Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-emulator, arraylist, android-2.2-froyo

I am New Android development. In My application I have two ArrayLists.

One ArrayList contains HashTbale. 
Another one contains HashTable

Now How can i set adpter and how to show in Listview image from Second ArrayList and Text From from ArrayList in ListView Row.

I am not able to get exact solution .

Please any one help in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if possible then give more detail of both the HashMap values. If possible i can suggest you to merge them into a single hashmap. Easy to handle.

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks for your Response.My Exact requirement is in LIstView i need to show image and text. But i cant maintain both in one ArrayList Thats Why i am using two arraylist. But i am not able to how to set adpter for listview using two ArrayLists

Comment: Just use HashMap arraylist which store both Image path and your text and set that single ArrayList to your Adapter. Also you can make a Custom Object ArrayList for your requirement. Just google you can find many examples..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display image and text in each row and if you are using 2 arraylist for the same then here is the solutions. Try this

```
List<Integer> imageList = getImageList();  //list of drawable ids
List<String> values = getValues();

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageList.size();;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate the layout which contains imageview and textview which are aligned horizontally. 
        //Assuming you inflated layout and got imageView and textview from that layout
        textView.setText(values.get(position));

        imageView.setImageResource(imageList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

//Code wont work if you directly copy paste. Use the logic and change accordingly

Instead of using 2 arraylist, my suggestion is you use HashMap. Imagepath as key and text as value.

Comment: @PareshMayani i agree. But he wanted to use 2 arraylists. so only i gave this solution

Comment: what about if both arraylist has a different size.  Or Text and Image are not related to each-other?

Answer (score 2):

**1st Suggestion: (Not proposed)**

Do you know how to define Custom adapter for ListView? If yes then you can easily pass two arraylist to your custom adapter. And inside `getView()` method, you can display whatever details you wants in ListView

**2nd Suggestion: (Proposed solution)**

If You make one ArrayList of CustomObject then there is no need to pass two ArrayList in Adapter.

Comment: If He makes one ArrayList of CustomObject then there is no need to pass two ArrayList in Adapter.

Comment: @user370305 thats the idea i was trying to convey in my above comments.

Comment: 1st suggestion not works if both arraylist has a different size.  Or Text and Image are not related to each-other.